# Count no. of categories within categories in my df in R

Tags: r, count

Each row of data in my df is from a study (or "Article").  Each Article has a sponsor ("Sponsor") who may have sponsored a number of the articles in my dataset.

I want to produce a summary table to show how many articles each Sponsor has sponsored in my dataset.

I hope you can help!

many thanks!!!!

Annabel

Comment: An example of your df would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

What I presume your dataframe looks like:

```
df=data.frame(article=1:10,sponsor=letters[round(runif(10,1,5))])
head(df)
```

> ```
>   article sponsor
> 1       1       a
> 2       2       b
> 3       3       e
> 4       4       d
> 5       5       e
> 6       6       b
> ```

How you could quickly check the number of articles per sponsor:

```
table(df$sponsor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but 
I guess what you are looking for is:

```
table(df$Sponsor)
```

If you want the value that occurs the most frequent, you can use:

```
names(sort(table(df$Sponsor), decreasing=TRUE))[1]
```

next time, please try to provide a MWE so it is easier for us to help.